# How to iterate over a mixed list using foreach?

Tags: java, generics, foreach

I'm wondering how to iterate over a List with mixed contents using foreach. See the example code below.

```
public class GenericsForeach {

    class A {
        void methodA() {
            System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + ": A");
        }
    }

    class B extends A {
        void methodB() {
            System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + ": B");
        }
    }

    void test() {

        List<A> listOfA = new ArrayList<A>();
        listOfA.add(new A());

        List<B> listOfB = new ArrayList<B>();
        listOfB.add(new B());

        List<? super A> mixed = new ArrayList<A>();
        mixed.addAll(listOfA);
        mixed.addAll(listOfB);

        Iterator<? super A> it = mixed.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            A item = (A) it.next();
            item.methodA();
        }

        // XXX: this does not work
        // for (A item : mixed) {
        // item.methodA();
        // }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GenericsForeach().test();
    }
}
```

I construct two lists with different, but related, content types `A` and `B` (`B` extends `A`). I add the two lists to a 'mixed' list, which I declare to contain `<? super A>` types. Since this mixed list is 'consuming' items of type `A` (or `B`) I applied Bloch's PECS rule (Producer Extends, Consumer Super) to determine that I need `<? super A>` here.

So far, so good. But now when I want to iterate over this mixed list, I can only seem to do it with an `Iterator<? super A>`, and a cast `A item = (A) it.next()`. When I try to use a foreach loop (see commented-out code), no joy:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type capture#8-of ? super GenericsForeach.A to GenericsForeach.A

Eclipse even helpfully offers to

> Change type of 'item' to '? super A'

but this results in disaster:

```
for (? super A item : mixed) {
    item.methodA();
}
```

So I don't know. Eclipse doesn't seem to know. Does anybody else here know if this is possible, and if it's not, why not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want just `List<A>` for `mixed`. My reasoning:

- you want to be able to add items which are of type `A`, so it can't be `List<? extends A>` - that would include `List<B>`, which you can't add an `A` to.
- you want to be able to guarantee that items which you *fetch* are of type `A`, so it can't be `List<? super A>` as that could be a `List<Object>` containing non-A elements.

So you end up with:

```
List<A> mixed = new ArrayList<A>();
mixed.addAll(listOfA);
mixed.addAll(listOfB);

for (A item : mixed) {
  item.methodA();
}
```

Comment: I agree.. Wanted to say the same, but you are way too quick for me :)

Comment: I'd hoped it would be more complicated than that... (-; Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Everyone here is correct.  You want use `List<A>`.

But generics and assignments can be confusing, so a little more explanation is in order.

First, the problem you may have found is that you can't do this:  `List<A> = new List<B>()`.  The compiler won't let you assign a sub-type in to a super-type listing using generics.  This is a little confusing, but it prevents problems with type mis-matches.  (More detail can be found here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html.)  The correct terminology for this is `List<? extends A> = new List<B>()`.  This tells the compiler that your assignment is legal.

At the same time, this syntax can confuse you to believing that `<? extends A>` means that all elements in this variable extend A.  This isn't true - the syntax just a way to inform the compiler of legal assignments.

So, you want to use `List<A> = new List<A>` and then assign the elements to `List<A>` using `addAll()`.  This is legal because the method addAll checks to make sure each element is valid before pushing it to the collection.